# What is a word for "being forced into submission"?

Tags: word-choice, paraphrasing

I have a quote in my essay but I don't remember where I got it from, so I need to remove and paraphrase it. Here's my original sentence:

> The belief that, as Christian women, queens should behave meekly is a reflection of the “submissiveness that a male-dominated Church and society imposed on women.”

I'm trying to rewrite it as:

> The belief that, as Christian women, queens should behave meekly is a reflection of the Church and society's [word for "forced submission"] of women.

Does "coercion" work here? If not, do you have any other suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: How about ‘domination’.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to know how it will be received in your local context as there can be a different perception of acceptability dependent on the culture. From [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/subjugation):

> **subjugation** noun
>
> [mass noun]
>
> The action of bringing someone or something under domination or
>   control.
>
> - ‘the colonial subjugation of a country by means of brute military force’
> - ‘the fear of human subjugation by technology’
>
> [count noun] [an act of subjugation]
>
> - ‘conquests and subjugations that we think are long forgotten’

Here is a biblical example, also from Lexico:

> - "Eve's deception by the serpent has been used to justify the subjugation of women in the Judeo-Christian tradition."